# [OSX][PHP 5.5.5] Ignored --with-config-file-scan-dir

Tags: php, macos, osx-mavericks, configure

I upgraded OSX Lion to Mavericks and decided to upgrade my PHP version to the latest at the time (5.5.5)

I managed to get all dependencies, configuration, make and installation to work, however after running it, it is ignoring the scan directory and using the one originally set by Apple.

### Apple original

The `php-config` showed

```
--configure-options [... --with-config-file-scan-dir=/Library/Server/Web/Config/php ...]
```

And the `php -i` showed

```
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 5.4.17

System => Darwin aeris-mba 13.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
Build Date => Aug 25 2013 01:47:44
Configure Command =>  '/private/var/tmp/apache_mod_php/apache_mod_php-87~65/php/configure'  
    ...
    '--with-config-file-path=/etc'
    '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/Library/Server/Web/Config/php'
    ...
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /Library/Server/Web/Config/php
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
PHP API => 20100412
PHP Extension => 20100525
Zend Extension => 220100525
...
```

You'll notice the Directory used is **`/Library/Server/Web/Config/php`**

---

### My Update

The `php-config` showed

```
--configure-options [... --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d ...]
```

And the `php -i` showed

```
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 5.5.5

System => Darwin aeris-mba 13.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
Build Date => Nov  2 2013 22:11:33
Configure Command =>  './configure'
    ...
    '--with-config-file-path=/etc'
    '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d'
    ...
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /Library/Server/Web/Config/php
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
PHP API => 20121113
PHP Extension => 20121212
Zend Extension => 220121212
```

You may now notice that 
`--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d`
but
`Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /Library/Server/Web/Config/php`

---

I have already configured, make and installed twice in case I missed anything, but to no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

I fixed the issue by running `make clean`.

Comment: Confirming that if you add or change the `--with-config-file-scan-dir` configure build flag while building PHP from source, that you need to run `make clean` for the change in build flag to be picked up correctly, otherwise the change does not seem to be correctly incorporated into the newly built PHP binary. This remedy also works with later versions of PHP, e.g. version 7. Running `make clean` after any change to the configure build flags will likely resolve similar flag value change recognition issues.